# How to add :00 to NumberPicker in Android?

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I have a NumberPicker which should represent hours. How can I add the :00 after the number? Or is there another way? Here's the code:

```
hourPicker.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    hourPicker.setMinValue(rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 2);
    hourPicker.setMaxValue(23);
    hourPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: You want to set :00 after you have picked an hour from the picker, right?

Comment: As soon as it starts I want the numbers to have the :00

Comment: So that the user can only pick hours like 15:00 / 16:00 / 10:00 etc.?

Comment: When it starts the user should see 8:00 and so on until 23:00

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957654/how-to-disable-minutes-change-in-timepickerdialog) answer, there is no direct way to restrict or disable the subviews of a TimePicker. You can copy the code from the Android SDK and try to edit it in a way useful for you, but that won't be an usual behavior for such a widget.

The other way is to allow the user to pick whatever time he/she wants and show an error message after the time selection, stating the the selected hour is wrong.

**EDIT:**
Please, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings) question. Check out the answer with the most votes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not using TimePicker. I am using NumberPicker because I only needed to show hours. Now, everything works fine, but I get numbers like this "8,9,12,13,14". I would like to somehow format them so :00 is added to all of them. Check my edited answer for a screenshot.

Comment: So on the left picker you have a date and on the right one you have and hour, right? And you just want to add :00 after the right picker?

Comment: I want the add the :00 in the right picker, not after it. So basically, instead of 8 I want it to be 8:00.

Comment: Yes, this way I can hard code the numbers, but I can't make the min value to get the current hour and add +2. :( Maybe it has to do something with the .setFormatter but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Did you set **min/maxValue()**?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116794/discussion-between-jlively-and-todor-kostov).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this like so:

```
String[] displayedValues  = new String[15];//23-8=15, so lenght needed is 15

for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
    displayedValues[i] = String.valueOf(8+i)+":00";//gives 8:00 for i=0 till 23:00 for i=15
}
```

and than

```
hourPicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);
```